# Jenkins scripted pipeline breaks while uploading the maven Artifact to Artifactory with 404 error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am using Jenkins's scripted pipeline and while uploading the Artifacts to Artifactory I am getting an error.

This is the code from my Jenkins scripted pipeline:

```
stage('Build') {

    rtMaven.run pom: 'java-proj/pom.xml', goals: '-X clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo;
}
```

The error which I am getting is:

> [main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoClientBuilder -
>   Failed checksum deploy of checksum 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>   with statusCode: 404

It uploads the artifacts half way and then somehow, it gets non zero exit code and it breaks the pipeline build.

I am using **[this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins)** Jfrog doc for reference and following exact syntax.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it’s the same issue, but I’ve seen this when one of the artifacts is a .md5, .sha1, or .sha256 extension. When such an artifact gets uploaded, artifactory appears to treat it as a checksum of an existing artifact in the repository. If an artifact of the same name without the hash extension does not exist then a 404 is thrown.

Comment: Thanks Scott for replying. Do you remember the Fix you applied to overcome from this issue?

Comment: I reported a bug to the JFrog support team and then renamed the artifact file to have a different extension other than above. In my case I changed the code to name the artifact <filename>.sha256.txt instead of <filename>.sha256. The JFrog support team however recommended just excluding the *.sha256 files from being uploaded to Artifactory by using spec file. The pointed to this example https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-pipeline-examples/resources/exclude-upload.json

Comment: Thanks Scott. I too did report to Jfrog and waiting on to hear from them. I looked at the exclude-upload.json which you shared but wondering how does this will co-relate with Jenkinsfile. Do I need to put any entries of it in the jenkinsfile or how

Comment: I suggest you create an upload spec file and put it in the repository with your Jenkinsfile. You can see an example of how they reference the spec file in Jenkinsfile DSL here: https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-pipeline-examples/exclude-patterns-upload-example/JenkinsFile. You can get docs on what a spec file looks like here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs. 

Not sure that would be helpful but it's a start.